# Photoshop CEP panel - select path to json file

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript, complex-event-processing

I am currently constructing my first photoshop CEP panel and I am struggling with how I can get the user to open a navigation panel to set the path to the data file I want to use in the script (JSON) and the folder containing the images I want to import.  Currently, I am using a defined location path in my script but to make it more useful they really need to be selectable.  I can find numerous examples of how this can be don't with a standard JSX script but have been unable to find an HTML/JS example.

All help appreciated.

Comment: There's a `window.cep.fs.showOpenDialog()` Have you tried to look through [CEP documentation](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/CEP-Resources/blob/master/CEP_8.x/Documentation/CEP%208.0%20HTML%20Extension%20Cookbook.md)? There're a lot of examples there.

Comment: I was unaware of this documentation @SergeyKritskiy, thank you for this.  I'm sure that this will provide me with the answers I need.  I will review it and add my solution to this question so as to help others.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Sergey Kritskiy's reply and a quick review of the CEP Documentation P63-64 I soon discovered that if you call `window.cep.fs.showOpenDialog()` from your CEP panel it will return a data object that contains an array of selected file paths.

```
$('#getData').on('click', function(){
  var obj = window.cep.fs.showOpenDialog();

  console.log(obj);
  //console.log(obj) can be viewed using chrome dev tools in the debug window
  //http://localhost:8088 - default for photoshop
  //Note: you will need to have added a .debug file to the root of your CEP panel extension
});
```

For full information on the return object, I would suggest using the CEP panel debug console

http://localhost:8088

Thank you Sergey!